# Android ampersand in preferences

Tags: android

I am storing a URL in my app throuhg a Preference Activity with an EditText.

As the default value, I am storing a url with an ampersand on it.

However when retrieving this preference from the app, I get the URL without ampersands.

This is how I store the URL:

```
<string name="pref_video_url_default">http://myserver.com/content/element?id=123&amp;value=3</string>
```

This is the preference:

```
 <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_url_default"
        android:key="url_setting"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textUri"
        android:title="@string/url_display" />
```

And this is how I retrieve it from code:

```
 String videoURL = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext())
                .getString("url_setting", "");
```

Fot the given example I am getting

```
http://myserver.com/content/element?id=123value=3
```

Comment: replace & with \u0026

Answer (score 0):

Modify your string resource. Change the `\&amp;` with `\u0026`. Using the unicode definition for ampersand will work.